# What is the origin of the term "post" as in "post a journal to the general ledger"

Tags: accounting, terminology

What is the origin of the term "post" as in "post a journal to the general ledger"?

I understand [what it means to post a journal](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/posting-in-accounting) but I'd love to know the origin of the term. I've not been able to find an explanation from Google, my intuition is that it might refer to a historic time when documents were sent from operations to the accounting department via the postal service, but it seems strange that a term in such general use would have originated only in organisations large enough to need to post things between sites.

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is better suited for english.SE rather money.SE